# DIY conference room with Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, video

What is the best DIY conference room setup?

Are there any free solutions that allow me to use a Raspberry Pi with a tv, webcam etc most importantly with its on dial in screen operable via remote (something like Google Meet).

Comment: TV? I'm sure there is sw, but I doubt this is going to work very well on a Rpi.